# how to calculate the generalization of one-vs-one classifier with Leave-out cross-validation?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, statistics, pattern-recognition

As a fundamental question about machine learning problems, I want to know how to calculate the generalization of my classifier with this description:

1. Dataset properties:

   - number of samples: 220
   - number of features: 19
   - number of class: 7
2. Method of classification:

   - support Vector Machines.
   - As you now, my classification's task is related to classifying one sample into 7 classes, So I've used from one-vs-one approach and then utilizing from majority-voting approach. [Procedure of classification: I create 21 classifiers, and then for each sample I classify it with 21 classifier separately. until this step, I've got 21 class label (1,2,3,4,5,6,7). Then, I go to next step and count the number of each label (This is called Majority Voting), for example for input x: #Class Label ONE = 7, #TWO = 5, #THREE = 4, #FOUR = 1, #FIVE = 1, #SIX = 1, #SEVEN = 2.]. I will assign each sample to any class which has greater degree in Majority-Process.

So with This Description, how to analyze my classifier regrading to generalization issue.

I will welcome any code in MATLAB that can help me.

```
load('dataset.mat');

X_train = data_train;
X_test = data_test;

[train_size, feature_size, class_size] = size(X_train);
[test_size] = size(X_test,1);

x = [];
for index=1:class_size
x=[x;X_test(:,:,index)];
end
X_test = x;

correct_label = [];
for index=1:class_size
     correct_label = [correct_label;index*ones(test_size,1)];
end

g = [];
C = 1;
for i=class_size:-1:1
    for j=1:(i-1)
        train = [X_train(:,:,j);X_train(:,:,i)];
        y = [j*ones(train_size,1);i*ones(train_size,1)];      
        svmModel = fitcsvm(train, y,'Standardize',true,'KernelFunction','GHI_Kernel');
        group = predict(svmModel, X_test);
        g = [g,group];
    end
end
temp = zeros(size(X_test,1),class_size);
n = size(X_test,1);
for i=1:n
     for j=1:class_size
          temp(i,j) = sum(((g(i,:)==j)'));
     end
end
%% esm1 contains the predicted class label
%% val1 contains the number of voting for predicted class label
[val1, esm1] = max(temp,[],2);

%% Calculating Confidence Matrix
for idx=1:n
     temp(idx,esm1(idx))=0;
end
[val2, esm2] = max(temp,[],2);
confidence_matrix = zeros(class_size, class_size);
counter = zeros(class_size, class_size);

for idx=1:n
     confidence_matrix(esm1(idx), correct_label(idx))...
          = confidence_matrix(esm1(idx), correct_label(idx)) + ...
          (val1(idx) - val2(idx))/val1(idx);
     counter(esm1(idx), correct_label(idx)) = ...
          counter(esm1(idx), correct_label(idx)) + 1;
end

for idx=1:class_size
    confidence_matrix(:,idx) = confidence_matrix(:,idx)/sum(confidence_matrix(:,idx));
end

CCR = sum(esm1 == correct_label)/size(correct_label,1);
plot_confusion_matrix(esm1, correct_label);
error = 1 - CCR;
confusion_matrix = confusionmat(esm1, correct_label);
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing facility. You should provide your code and the famous MATLAB gurus might help to improve your code, but we will not solve your problem by writing your code :).

Comment: @StephenReindl So here is code :)

Comment: Could you narrow the scope of your question?

Comment: @tashuhka. yeap. It's actually related to generalization of classifier. I want to know how the leave-out approach works and also calculate for my classifier. by the way, I think the question header is obvious.

Comment: One widely-used approach for evaluating multiclass classifiers is to construct a so-called "confusion matrix" (i.e. table in which element (i, j) is the number of data for which the true class is i and the output class is j). A web search for that term should turn up a lot of hits.

Comment: @RobertDodier, Hello Sir, I know the usage of Confusion matrix but I think it's not criterion for evaluation of generalization!